# Laravel 5 routing issue on redirecting url

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I am new to laravel runing a project in it,i got error when i enter a module name to url **NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161**
[image]

And here is my **routes.php** file Code:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'Landing@index']);
Route::get('/buyerregistration',['as' => 'buyerregistration', function () {
    return view('buyerregistration');
}]);

Route::get('owarehouse/{id}',  ['as' => 'owarehouse',function () {
    return view('owarehouse');
}]);

Route::get('/SMM',  ['as' => 'SMM',function () {
    return view('SMM');
}]);

Route::get('productconsumer/{id}/{openwish_id?}',array(
 'as' => 'productconsumer', 
 'uses' => 'ProductController@productconsumer'));
```

I have **.htacces** file in my /public folder as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this,
Thanks

Comment: Try with lowercase characters

Comment: @kotapeter it's not working.

Comment: weird, what does `php artisan route:list` gave out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable Mod_rewrite in your Xampp/Wampp's Apache.
   Go to `{xampp_dir/wampp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and find the line 
   `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` and remove the # before it.
2. Allow Apache to Overwrite the htaccess file from anywhere. Find the line 
   `AllowOverride None` and change it to `AllowOverride All`

Try `localhost/Opensupermall/public/SMM` 
The code here points to your views after the public folder.
Now,the best practice would be in production to make your server's root folder to point the /public/ folder

```
Route::get('/SMM',  ['as' => 'SMM',function () {
return view('SMM');
}]);
```

So you just type your route names after your root directory name.

Comment: thanks for answer, i have tried that but it give me 404 error.

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite in your xampp/wamp for your apache? If you haven't enabled your URL routing wont work.

Comment: Hmm, have you allowed overrides of your htaccess files in the apache config ?

Comment: No,how do i do that?

Comment: ok go to your `{xampp_dir/wampp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf` then if you have'nt already enabled the rewrite engine remove the # before this line `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`  and after you have done this go on search for the line `AllowOverride None` and replace it with `AllowOverride All` then restart your apache Server and you must be able to access the route at `localhost/Opensupermall/public/SMM`

Comment: where should i put my htaccess file in root or in public forlder?

Comment: tellme if this url works `localhost/Opensupermall/public/index.php/SMM`

Comment: yeah,got something new other than routing error,it's for view can't load

Comment: Route [search] not defined. (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\OpenSupermall\resources\views\common\header.blade.php) (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\OpenSupermall\resources\views\common\header.blade.php) (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\OpenSupermall\resources\views\common\header.blade.php)

Comment: please update the answer and tell me whati need to change in my htaccess file

Comment: glad i could help ! yea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99582/discussion-between-priyank57-and-karthic-rajakumar).